# Order factor variable in barplot with facet and group fill

Tags: r, plot, ggplot2, bar-chart

My data is a `table()` output on four variables (data is below).

I want to plot N per V3, filled by V1 and faceted by V2. But before, V1 shall be ordered by V4.

```
temp$V1 <- reorder(temp$V1, temp$V4)
ggplot(temp, aes(x=V3, y=N, fill=V1)) +
  geom_bar(binwidth = 10, stat="identity") +
  ylab("") + xlab("") +
  facet_grid(. ~ V2) +
  scale_fill_discrete(name = "Journal") +
  theme(legend.title = element_text(colour="black", size=14),
        legend.direction="horizontal",
        legend.position="bottom",
        strip.text.x = element_text(size = 14),
        axis.text = element_text(colour="black", size=10),
        axis.ticks.x = element_blank(),
        panel.grid.minor.x=element_blank(),
        panel.grid.major.x=element_blank()
  )
```

But the bar elements are still not ordered according my desired rule for my output looks like

[image]

The order should be JBF, JFI, JMCB, JF, JFE, RFS. What am I doing wrong? Are there too many dimensions?

Here is the data:

```
    V1    V2    V3     V4   N
    JBF  1998   with    0   97
    JFI  1998   with    0   21
    JMCB 1998   with    0   62
    JBF  1999   with    0   93
    JFI  1999   with    0   20
    JMCB 1999   with    0   37
    JBF  2000   with    0   112
    JFI  2000   with    0   29
    JMCB 2000   with    0   65
    JBF  2009   with    0   247
    JFI  2009   with    0   40
    JMCB 2009   with    0   126
    JBF  2010   with    0   299
    JFI  2010   with    0   27
    JMCB 2010   with    0   110
    JBF  2011   with    0   311
    JFI  2011   with    0   34
    JMCB 2011   with    0   120
    JBF  1998   without 0   29
    JMCB 1998   without 0   9
    JBF  1999   without 0   62
    JMCB 1999   without 0   16
    JBF  2000   without 0   37
    JFI  2000   without 0   2
    JMCB 2000   without 0   20
    JBF  2009   without 0   158
    JFI  2009   without 0   2
    JMCB 2009   without 0   23
    JBF  2010   without 0   153
    JFI  2010   without 0   2
    JMCB 2010   without 0   28
    JBF  2011   without 0   133
    JFI  2011   without 0   1
    JMCB 2011   without 0   12
    JF   1998   with    1   133
    JFE  1998   with    1   91
    RFS  1998   with    1   44
    JF   1999   with    1   134
    JFE  1999   with    1   101
    RFS  1999   with    1   72
    JF   2000   with    1   147
    JFE  2000   with    1   101
    RFS  2000   with    1   74
    JF   2009   with    1   154
    JFE  2009   with    1   181
    RFS  2009   with    1   284
    JF   2010   with    1   128
    JFE  2010   with    1   179
    RFS  2010   with    1   218
    JF   2011   with    1   103
    JFE  2011   with    1   249
    RFS  2011   with    1   189
    JF   1998   without 1   12
    JFE  1998   without 1   2
    JF   1999   without 1   18
    JFE  1999   without 1   2
    RFS  1999   without 1   3
    JF   2000   without 1   8
    JFE  2000   without 1   6
    RFS  2000   without 1   2
    JF   2009   without 1   6
    JFE  2009   without 1   4
    RFS  2009   without 1   4
    JFE  2010   without 1   9
    RFS  2010   without 1   8
    JF   2011   without 1   3
    JFE  2011   without 1   7
    RFS  2011   without 1   9
```

**Editor: output of `dput(temp)`**

```
structure(list(V1 = structure(c(3L, 2L, 1L, 3L, 2L, 1L, 3L, 2L, 
1L, 3L, 2L, 1L, 3L, 2L, 1L, 3L, 2L, 1L, 3L, 1L, 3L, 1L, 3L, 2L, 
1L, 3L, 2L, 1L, 3L, 2L, 1L, 3L, 2L, 1L, 6L, 4L, 5L, 6L, 4L, 5L, 
6L, 4L, 5L, 6L, 4L, 5L, 6L, 4L, 5L, 6L, 4L, 5L, 6L, 4L, 6L, 4L, 
5L, 6L, 4L, 5L, 6L, 4L, 5L, 4L, 5L, 6L, 4L, 5L), .Label = c("JMCB", 
"JFI", "JBF", "JFE", "RFS", "JF"), class = c("ordered", "factor"
)), V2 = c("1998", "1998", "1998", "1999", "1999", "1999", "2000", 
"2000", "2000", "2009", "2009", "2009", "2010", "2010", "2010", 
"2011", "2011", "2011", "1998", "1998", "1999", "1999", "2000", 
"2000", "2000", "2009", "2009", "2009", "2010", "2010", "2010", 
"2011", "2011", "2011", "1998", "1998", "1998", "1999", "1999", 
"1999", "2000", "2000", "2000", "2009", "2009", "2009", "2010", 
"2010", "2010", "2011", "2011", "2011", "1998", "1998", "1999", 
"1999", "1999", "2000", "2000", "2000", "2009", "2009", "2009", 
"2010", "2010", "2011", "2011", "2011"), V3 = c("with", "with", 
"with", "with", "with", "with", "with", "with", "with", "with", 
"with", "with", "with", "with", "with", "with", "with", "with", 
"without", "without", "without", "without", "without", "without", 
"without", "without", "without", "without", "without", "without", 
"without", "without", "without", "without", "with", "with", "with", 
"with", "with", "with", "with", "with", "with", "with", "with", 
"with", "with", "with", "with", "with", "with", "with", "without", 
"without", "without", "without", "without", "without", "without", 
"without", "without", "without", "without", "without", "without", 
"without", "without", "without"), V4 = c("0", "0", "0", "0", 
"0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", 
"0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", 
"0", "0", "0", "0", "1", "1", "1", "1", "1", "1", "1", "1", "1", 
"1", "1", "1", "1", "1", "1", "1", "1", "1", "1", "1", "1", "1", 
"1", "1", "1", "1", "1", "1", "1", "1", "1", "1", "1", "1"), 
    N = c(97L, 21L, 62L, 93L, 20L, 37L, 112L, 29L, 65L, 247L, 
    40L, 126L, 299L, 27L, 110L, 311L, 34L, 120L, 29L, 9L, 62L, 
    16L, 37L, 2L, 20L, 158L, 2L, 23L, 153L, 2L, 28L, 133L, 1L, 
    12L, 133L, 91L, 44L, 134L, 101L, 72L, 147L, 101L, 74L, 154L, 
    181L, 284L, 128L, 179L, 218L, 103L, 249L, 189L, 12L, 2L, 
    18L, 2L, 3L, 8L, 6L, 2L, 6L, 4L, 4L, 9L, 8L, 3L, 7L, 9L)), .Names = c("V1", 
"V2", "V3", "V4", "N"), class = c("data.table", "data.frame"), row.names = c(NA, 
-68L), .internal.selfref = <pointer: 0x318e998>)
```

Comment: It seems that you want to reorder the factor like this; `temp$V1 <- factor(temp$V1, levels = c("JBF", "JFI", "JMCB", "JF", "JFE", "RFS"))`.

Comment: I cannot reproduce this problem: when I read in your table and run your code, the labels are in exactly the order you want. Could you provide the result of `dput(temp)`?

Comment: You should write `ordered = TRUE` as well to @jazzurro's answer like `temp$V1 <- factor(temp$V1, levels = c("JBF", "JFI", "JMCB", "JF", "JFE", "RFS"), ordered=T)`

Comment: I had a similar issue recently and could use `reorder` as shown [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/9231857/3521006).

Comment: After printing temp over and over again, I realized that the order of temp was the problem, not the plotting procedure nor the order of `temp$V1`. Answer is below. Nonetheless, I added the output of `dput(temp)` to help future readers. Thank you all.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The only command missing was to redefined `temp` before plotting:

```
temp <- temp[order(temp$V1), ]
```

Because in this case, `temp` is really ordered and not just virtually.